# Why doesn't navigator.share() work inside fetch API?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch, es6-promise, navigator

I have encountered a very interesting issue, where navigator.share() works fine outside the fetch, but not inside.

**Works:**

```
navigator.share({title: '1 Test title', text: '1 Test text'})
```

**Doesnt work:**

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/orgs/nodejs').then(r => r.json().then(d => {
    navigator.share({title: '2 Test title', text: '2 Test text'})
}))
```

**EDIT:** I'm currently testing it on IOS Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from this requirement:

> It must be invoked in response to a user action such as a click. Invoking it through the onload handler is impossible.
>   (https://web.dev/web-share/)

If you directly share from a click event it seems to be okay. If you share after a callback/promise it's not okay - event if this promise/callback functions was called from a click event (at least on iOS). The browser should see the user action in the call stack.

I ran across this, too. I think it behaves more like a bug than a feature since it prevents dynamic share possibilities.

**Solution**: Data to share must be available at the moment of actually sharing. So you might need to show another button or whatever to share the data you fetched.

Comment: The issue came from inside a onclick event. There seems to be a specific bug inside fetch share api.